# Need help showing that a function $f$ is continuous if and only it is upper and lower semi continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to use this definition of upper and lower semi continuous functions: $f: X \to R$ is l.s.c. if $x_n \to x \implies f(x) \le lim_{n \to \infty} \text{inf} f(x_n)$, and upper continuous if $f(x) \ge lim_{n\to \infty}\text{sup} f(x_n).$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Prove that $\liminf_nf(x_n)\le\limsup_nf(x_n)$.